# Combining sub-matrices by replacing zero elements with symbols

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a nested matrix as `m`:

```
m = {{a, b}, {c, d}}
a = {{e, f, g, h}, {0, 0, q, i}, {0, 0, q, j}};
b = {{e, f, g, h}, {s, 0, 0, i}, {s, 0, 0, j}};

c = {{e, f, g, h}, {0, u, 0, i}, {u, 0, 0, j}};
d = {{e, f, g, h}, {0, 0, t, i}, {0, t, 0, j}};
```

Its result in `MatrixForm` is as

[image]

but the desired final output must to be same as

[image]

If, instead of *symbols* such as `q, s, t ...`, I had just `1 and 0`, I could use of `{MapThread[Max, #, 2]} & /@ m`. But unfortunately I am faced with symbols and the comparison `max` does not work for symbols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{MapThread[Max, #, 2]} & /@ m /. Max[0, x_] :> x // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Perhaps a more sane way to do what you want (for your particular structure) would be to take advantage of the sorting of symbols after numbers:

```
{MapThread[(Last@Union@{##}) &, #, 2]} & /@ m // MatrixForm
```

Another method is to map the symbols to numbers (works for *your* structure, since only a symbol and a zero, or the same symbol, or two zeroes are ever compared), do your operation, then unmap them:

```
rules = With[{u = Cases[Union@Flatten@m, _Symbol]}, Thread[Rule[u, Range@Length@u]]];
({MapThread[Max, #, 2]} & /@ (m /. rules)) /. Reverse /@ rules
```

Comment: It is OK, But I am not able to insert a list={{JACK,JULLY}} as the first column in the final output nested matrix, I am trying with the command: Transpose[Insert[Transpose[m], Flatten@list, 1]]; but it doesn't work!?

Answer (score 3):

If the input is as shown I think using [`Total`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) is simpler:

```
List /@ Total /@ m /. {2 -> 1} // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  e & f & g & h \\
>  s & 0 & q & i \\
>  s & 0 & q & j \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  e & f & g & h \\
>  0 & u & t & i \\
>  u & t & 0 & j \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Or if you enjoy terse coding:

```
{+##} & @@@ m /. 2 -> 1
```

Comment: That was my first thought - but I decided not to assume there would be no "real" twos - else the OP could just manually enter the result... +1 o/c